# New Item Fields Automatic Population

Tags: column, calculated-column, date-time, list-item

I sure this is possible to do in SharePoint, however, I am not 100% sure on how it's to be done.  My objective is to 2 fields to automatically populate when adding a 'New Item' to an List Library.  The 2 fields are as follows:

1. Field #1, "**Employee**", to have the employee's name appear in the field automatically
2. Field #2, "**Date and Time**", to have today's date and time appear in the field automatically

I was thinking to approach "Field #2" by adding "=TEXT([Modified],"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")" into the calculated field.  However, I am not sure if this correct approach.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, yes, that would be the way to go, setting a default value but use [Today] instead. For #1, you'll need to resort to some scripting to achieve that, people columns can't have a default value. If you can use javascript/jquery, then you can retrieve that information and put it into a text field.

Using some jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com), it would be this:

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldNames: ["FirstName", "LastName"],
    debug: false
});
var userFullName = thisUsersValues.FirstName + " " + thisUsersValues.LastName;
$("input[Title='Display name of your column']").val(userFullName);
```